# Set path alias in angular 4 application

Tags: angular

Is there any way to set path aliases in Angular with TypeScript
since putting path like

```
import { AuthService } from '../../../common/AuthService';
import { ContactService } from '../../../common/ContactService';
```

It is very confusing i.e. to remember the relative path URI.
Is there any way to create path aliases and use them throughout the application, like **browserify**?

Comment: I suggest using a less deeply nested directory structure. If you are always importing the same two services, then another alternative would be to place a little stub-like module in a "nearby" place which re-exports those services.

Comment: You can use SystemJS for this. That is what makes it possible to import from '@angular/common' irrespective of the directory structure. Tooling can also help.  In IntelliJ, 'alt-enter' will automatically add the import.

Comment: You can also use absolute paths, such as `import { AuthService } from 'src/app/common/AuthService';`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use typescript, the best way to deal with this problem is to put paths configuration in project's tsconfig.json:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "@app/*": ["app/*"],
  "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
}
```

Please, refer 2nd point in the following article https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/6-best-practices-pro-tips-for-angular-cli-better-developer-experience-7b328bc9db81, or official ts docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url